# ruby: minimal setup for writing given when then tests with spec

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm ruby to do given when then tests in ruby (not rails)

I have an empty folder called infrastrucure. It has a folder called spec.
In it is a folder called features. In that, I have a feature called foo which is like this:

```
~/gray/infrastructure (master *)[]$ cat spec/features/foo.feature 
Scenario: View last incidents
  Given Linda is logged in # This will in fact invoke 2 step definitions
  When I go to the incident page
```

When I run the spec command, the feature files are ignored.
Whats am I missing?

fyi here's my gem environment:

```
~/gray/infrastructure (master *)[]$ rvm-prompt
ruby-2.3.0-preview1@infrastructure
~/gray/infrastructure (master *)[]$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.7)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cucumber (2.3.2)
cucumber-core (1.4.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
did_you_mean (1.0.0.beta3)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
gherkin (3.2.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.2)
minitest (5.8.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.0.14)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rspec (3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.4.4)
rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.1.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written cucumber features, not RSpec feature tests.  Cucumber features should be in a folder called features at the same level as your spec folder.  They are run with `cucumber` not `spec`